# Mismatch in SPFX ListviewCommandSet buttons visibility in modern Document Library

Tags: spfx, spfx-tooling, spfx-extensions, command-set, listviewcommandset

When I set the visibility of the the custom button, It should be applicable at both places (ContextMenu + CommandBar).
I am having 2 buttons (Add Fav + Remove Fav). Based on few conditions, i am setting them up as visible = true / false.
So this visibility setting should be applied globally for both (ContextMenu + CommandBar) but shows otherwise behavior.

Steps to Reproduce
Consecutive attempts to add and remove favorite button for an item leads to this button mismatch . This is my element.xml file structure::

```
 <CustomAction
        Title="FavouriteButton"
        RegistrationId="101"
        RegistrationType="List"
        Location="ClientSideExtension.ListViewCommandSet"
        ClientSideComponentId="guid">
    </CustomAction>
```

and commandsetManifest.json file

```
 "items": {
    "AddFavourite": {
      "title": { "default": "Add to Favourites" },
      "iconImageUrl": "/Fav.png",
      "type": "command"
    },
    "RemoveFavourite": {
      "title": { "default": "Remove from Favourites" },
      "iconImageUrl": "/RemoveFav.png",
      "type": "command"
    }
  }
```

SS: [image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug and SPFX community have accepted this and will fix this in future releases. 
Thank you team for the affirmative response.

Reference : [**#1459**](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/1459)